# Looking for a Sega Master System game called "Dragon"

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I saw a Master System game called *Dragon* in a video called "Top 20 Co-Op Master System Games", but when I searched for it, I only found *Dragon Crystal* or *Double Dragon* in the results, but not this game. It looks like the video is the only proof that it exists. I think it might be false, but there's actual gameplay and I don't see any reason why they would do that (put it in the list).

The game itself is a fighting and platform game for the Sega Master System. Can anyone help me find it?

Comment: top 20 co op master system games -> Timestamp and link, pls

Comment: How exactly does this have anything to to with sci-fi or fantasy?

Comment: wthout more than a text descripotion it's off-topic for Arqade
(https://gaming.stackexchange.com) too.

Comment: @Amarth - Because it's about dragons

Comment: @Valorum Except _Enter the Dragon_ is not about dragons at all... you'd call Bruce Lee movies fantasy?

Comment: @Amarth - In the absence of any specific information to the contrary, all we know is that OP though about crystal dragons

Comment: @DAVI BORGES - Is my answer below correct? If it is, please mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. If it's incorrect, please say so, to confirm that. Also, please provide a link to the YouTube video you watched, so we can see it for ourselves. Thanks

Comment: @DAVI BORGES - Are you aware that you can leave comments by clicking on the `Add a comment` link directly beneath your question?

Answer (score 5):

Is this the video you were referring to...?

If so, aside from *Double Dragon*, I saw only one other Sega Master System game mentioned with 'Dragon' in the title, and that was ***[Dragon: The Bruce Lee Story](https://segaretro.org/Dragon:_The_Bruce_Lee_Story_(8-bit))***.

> *Dragon: The Bruce Lee Story* is a Sega Master System and Sega Game Gear platform game based on the 1993 *Dragon: The Bruce Lee Story* film.

Comment: Almost certainly [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNWXTj4fhzY&t=785s) is the video. And the timestamp has Bruce Lee and the word "Dragon";